# RabbitMQ, NodeJS, Express internal server errror

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Anyone know why this is not working. These pieces of code have been taken from examples. I have no stack trace to show you as my NodeJS debugging skills are currently rubbish. Any help would be much appreciated.

Note I do have the RabbitMQ server running and a receiver has been able to connect.

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var when = require('when');
var rabbitmq_conn = amqp.connect('amqp://localhost' );

function push_keystroke_data(session_id, data) {
  var QUEUE_NAME = 'hello';
  var msg = session_id;

  //1
  rabbitmq_conn.on('ready',
    function () {
      rabbitmq_conn.createChannel(
        function(err, ch) {
          ch.assertQueue(QUEUE_NAME, {
                exclusive: true,
                durable: true
            }, function(err, ok) {
            }
          );
        }
      );
    }
  );

  //2
  when(rabbitmq_conn.createChannel()).then(function(ch) {
    var ok = ch.assertQueue(QUEUE_NAME, {durable: false});

    ok.then(function(_qok) {
      ch.sendToQueue(QUEUE_NAME, new Buffer(msg));
      console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
      ch.close();
    });

  }).ensure(function() {
    conn.close();
  });

}
```

This is the receivers code:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {

    var QUEUE_NAME = 'hello';
    var ok = ch.assertQueue(QUEUE_NAME, {durable: false});

    ok = ok.then(function(_qok) {
      return ch.consume(QUEUE_NAME, function(msg) {
        console.log(" [x] Received '%s'", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true});
    });

    return ok.then(function(_consumeOk) {
      console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C');
    });
  });
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amqplib provide two parallel client APIs. One uses promises, and the other uses callbacks. You are free to choose which you prefer, they don't mix -- a channel from the promises API has only the promise-based methods, and likewise the callback API.

The promise-based API is the "main" module in the library:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
```

You can access the callback-based API this way:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
```

In the sender code, you have also mixed the [amqp lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp) methods. ie *ready* event. Stick to one library and API's.

This is the same code for Sender

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');
var when = require('when');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  return when(conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
    var q = 'hello';
    var msg = 'Hello World!';

    var ok = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

    return ok.then(function(_qok) {
      ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
      console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
      return ch.close();
    });
  })).ensure(function() { conn.close(); });;
}).then(null, console.warn);
```